# App Won't Run On Emulator After Updating? Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-manifest, android-studio-2.2

I have an app I have been reskinning, and after updating some portion of Android Studio (Don't know exactly what it was, I just clicked update because this happens often), the app won't run on the emulator! The emulator opens, and is working fine with other apps, just not this one. Even a version of the app that I know works, because I tested it and took screenshots of it a few days ago. I don't know why it isn't opening on the emulator... This is what it tells me.

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

What does this mean? I've tried to find the solution on other questions, but they are outdated and no longer relevant to the versions of build tools, etc. that my app is using. All help is very much appreciated! Thank You.

Comment: Please provide 
    <project_directory>/<app_directory>/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt

Comment: there should be some duplicated config in manifest OR some typo for package name. anyway paste both manifest and gradle files to get better help

Comment: @MaxV Commented Below with the logcat, build.gradle, and manifest.

Comment: @EliasFazel Commented Below with the logcat, build.gradle, and manifest.

Comment: what is your android studio version? Shaow your gradle and manifest files.

Comment: Do One thing Close Your  Android Studio and go to C:\Users\YourDevicwName. and delete .gradle folder. and again start android studio. If not working do from android studeo file/invalidatecache and restart